# How can I use the model DMOS NMOS in a .mod file shown in the picture below?

Tags: ltspice

I'm trying to implement a CS amplifier with the model DMOS NMOS, but I'm having difficulties with how to import and use the given model DMOS NMOS in my circuit, I've been trying to look for tutorials but so far I have not figured it out.
Any help is welcomed.
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify if you want to use just the `.MODEL DMOS NMOS...` part or the [entire BS170 subcircuit](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/collateral/bs170.mod) from ON Semiconductor?

Comment: @Ste Kulov I just want to use the .MODEL DMOS NMOS part

Comment: Does this help? https://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/book/chapter7/ch7_5.htm

Comment: Just copy the line(s) with the relevant parts and use it/them in your schematic.

Comment: @a concerned citizen I suppose that is generally how it is done, but I think I need some more specific instructions